# How to make VoiceOver read keyboard shortcuts correctly?

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility

I'm trying to get VoiceOver working with the [MASShortcut keyboard shortcut control](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut). Things mostly work but I've run into one snag.

When I return the shortcut's description string from -accessibilityLabel, VoiceOver reads it correctly, as "Shift Command M". If I return the same description string from -accessibilityTitle (or any other accessibility value, it seems), VoiceOver reads it instead as "Upwards Wide Arrow Command M".

This wouldn't be an issue, except that I need a way to trigger VoiceOver to read the new shortcut value after it has been set. I can post an NSAccessibilityTitleChangedNotification, but there is no corresponding NSAccessibilityLabelChangedNotification.

I tried NSAccessibilityAnnouncementRequestedNotification, but that also gets read out as "Upwards Wide Arrow".

Does anyone know of a way to hint this string (or return a different description string for VoiceOver) that will always read correctly? Or, as a workaround, a way to force VoiceOver to re-read the accessibilityLabel?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hey man, please let me know once you have your branch up and I’m going to take a look.